# Trying to escape space in a NSString object

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring, escaping

I have a path that might contain spaces that I later want to pass as an argument to a shell script, running on macOS. In order for this to work I have to escape the spaces, in the same manner as bash does when I do command completion, with a backspace character.

Example: This is a path to start with:

`dbHome="/Library/Application Support/MimerSQL"`

This is what I want to have after escaping spaces:

`dbHome="/Library/Application\ Support/MimerSQL"`

In order to do this replacement I call `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` thus:

`dbHome = [dbHome stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\ "];`

but that gives me a compiler warning ("Unknown escape sequence '\ '") and a resulting string that is the same as the original. I then tried to escape the backspace character thus:

`dbHome = [dbHome stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\\ "];`

and that got rid of the compiler warning but it instead resulted in a totally different string than I wanted:

`dbHome="/Library/Application\\ Support/MimerSQL"`

So I am stuck. :(

Bottom line: how can I go from "...Application Support..." to "...Application\ Support..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing right way. To achieve it, you need to replace `@" "` with `@"\\ "`.

You will see in debug like

```
/Library/Application\\ Support/MimerSQL
```

but when you try to log or use it, it will be as expected.

```
/Library/Application\ Support/MimerSQL
```

Comment: Indeed. I added a NSLog and it showed up correctly. Very confusing that there are two backslashes in the Xcode symbol view

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
        NSString *dbHome=@"/Library/Application Support/MimerSQL";
        NSString *spaceString =@" ";
        NSString *backslash = @"\\";
        dbHome = [dbHome stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",backslash,spaceString]];
```

Comment: I tried that before I posted -- it did the same thing as my example.